# can I see what the aggregation pipeline results look like part way through?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

[Map Reduce has this ability](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/), but I can't find it in aggregation. I thought that there was a way to output/troubleshoot/debug the aggregation pipeline results midway through, but I don't see anything like that in the [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

I've got an aggregation that's not working now that I've added the $year to the $project stage:

```
}, {
    $project: {
        "week": { "$week": "$ts"},
        "year": {"$year": "$ts"},
        "name": "$name",
        "id": "$_id"
    }
}, {
```

Can I output the results after this $project stage to see what the result looks like?

Comment: Sure, just remove the pipeline stages that follow it.

Comment: Well that was easy. Make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks. I was thinking there'd be an $output operator of some sort ($print, $emit, something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can end a pipeline with any operator, so just remove the pipeline stages that follow the point at which you want to see the intermediate result.